# JOE and ftyperc

Tags: joe

Is there a way to set, for example, the right margin for all files in a specific directory?

For example, set the right margin to 125 for all files in `$HOME/bin` but leave the default for files in `$HOME/Mail`.

I've tried lots of things and cannot get any to work.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, even if it doesn't work? You might be almost there.

Comment: I've tried:

*~/bin/* and
*$HOME/bin/*.     How do I add a line feed to these comments?

Comment: To share your tries you should add to your question the actual command(s) and the output you get.

Comment: In this case, I do not get any output, it simply does not set the right margins.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.  Either of these added to my ftyperc file do the trick for setting the right margin to 125 for files in the $HOME/bin directory:

```
* $HOME/bin/*
-rmargin 125

* ~/bin/*
-rmargin 125
```